# JQuery - making a list of img toggles go to their default image when one of them is toggled

Tags: jquery, image, list, toggle

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/7/).

There are two divs with four imgs. I would like the first div to toggle between two imgs and the second div to toggle between two imgs. I would also like the other div to default to the first img when the other div is toggled.

HTML:

```
<div class="home">
    <img src="http://www.misfitpsycles.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Red-Circle.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="http://tribute.dbclay.com/img/badjorx/black-circle.jpg">
</div>
<div class="myPlayer">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Blue_Circle_o.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/301/829/308/308829301_525.jpg">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".home img").toggle(function () {
    $(this).attr('img', "http://api.ning.com/files/fKlV2*stZybazIWAVKY3Mp3ceSTbNHhqgbBTXhdqDPoZ4SnroGQhXGtxNNpDGexaWmh3mmlm*IA3BlneAW5eYAGsPy--S5Vv/Black_circle8cf6f.jpg");
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('img', "http://wolfelawmiami.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/RED-CIRCLE-3.jpg");
});

$(".myPlayer img").toggle(function () {
    $(this).attr('img', "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Blue_Circle_o.jpg");
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('img', "http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/301/829/308/308829301_525.jpg");
});
```

Comment: What event should cause the toggle to occur? Is it a click, a hover?

Comment: Clicking would flip the images back and forth. I haven't added the css yet, but the imgs within the divs would be on top of each other and hide the other after clicking.

Comment: I can get the toggle working. I can't get the other div to automatically default to the original img when the other div is toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I had a look at your JSFiddle. Rather than modify your one I approached it how I normally would with these considerations:

1) I have added some CSS changes to your fiddle to lay it out so it's easier to see the results in the JSFiddle
2) You haven't specified what event should cause the toggle, so I have done it based off a click on the div.
3) You're already loading the images in the page, so changing the src is an odd approach IMO, you may as well just change the visibility of the two images.

Here is a JS fiddle demo of how I would approach this using a click function and using classes to identify and change the images.

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img:hidden').addClass('tofadein');
    $(this).find('img:visible').addClass('tofadeout');
    $(this).find('img.tofadein').fadeIn();
    $(this).find('img.tofadeout').fadeOut();
    $(this).find('img').removeClass();  

      $(this).siblings('div').find('img').eq(0).fadeIn();
    $(this).siblings('div').find('img').eq(1).fadeOut();
});
```

[JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/9/)

Comment: Thanks!! That's much better. I got the src approach from stackoverflow.

Comment: Good to hear, if this has answered your question then please remember to mark this answer as correct. Otherwise if you need some clarification on the answer let me know.

Comment: James, I'm now trying for more than two divs. Could you take a look at my updates? http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/11/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple approach.  I don't understand what you wanted from the second request though.  Can you specify? "I would also like the other div to default to the first img when the other div is toggled."

```
$('div').on('click', 'img', function(){
    var c = $(this).closest('div').attr('class');
   $('.'+ c + ' img').toggle();
});
```

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alutz33/7eDSN/

Comment: I meant that the first div would default back to the original img when the second div is toggled. So in your example, if you toggle red to the black empty circle, then toggle the blue circle to the green circle, then the black empty circle would toggle back to red automatically. Hope that helps. See James example. It works. I got the toggles to work as in your example, but couldn't get the first div to auto toggle back to the red circle.